# linux-zen VS cfs-zen-tweaks

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-parameters

I'm using Arch on a very old computer with Chrome and it crashes pretty often, plus the CPU consumption is very high.

I read that using cfs-zen-tweaks could improve the responsiveness.

Which is better, using cfs-zen-tweaks or a linux-zen kernel? What is the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an older laptop with low processing power as well, I use it on the go as it's very light and the battery lasts quite long. It wasn't unstable, though, but got unresponsive whenever I did an update in the background. I run Arch on it.

I moved from the vanilla kernel over to the cfs-zen tweaks, which made a difference in responsiveness. I wanted even more and installed the zen kernel, I can't really tell the difference to the cfs-patches allone, but in general it is responding really well even in stressfull situations.

Just give it a go and test it out, on most distributions it's quite easy to switch back and forth between the zen kernel and the vanilla kernel.

Comment: Then I think I'll just use the tweaks, for the sake of simplicity. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A different kernel is **highly unlikely** to improve the application CPU use but it may make your system slightly more responsive.

> cfs-zen-tweaks or a linux-zen kernel

Haven't used any, been using the vanilla kernel since forever. The difference is down to applied patches and defaults.

> Chrome crashes pretty often

This could indicate bad RAM which you could test using [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/download.htm)

Comment: Testing with htop showed me that the issue seemed to be more the CPU than the RAM, but I'll try memtest86, thanks! And yes I didn't want to reduce the CPU usage, I just wanted to make it more responsive and I'd like it to freeze instead of crashing.